mockito chain args match is not support
When I used chained mocks, there was a problem. For example, I needed to return different values ​​according to the different parameters of the intermediate chained methods. When I used it, a null pointer exception occurred.
1、chain
2、args seq

version:
  <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.11.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mockito/mockito-inline -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-inline</artifactId>
            <version>4.11.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mockito/mockito-junit-jupiter -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>4.11.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

jdk: 1.8
os: window 10
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class TestLink {
    @Test
    public void testMockChain() {
        Mockito.mockConstruction(Link.class, withSettings().defaultAnswer(RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS), (mock, context) -> {
            if (context.arguments().get(1).equals("z")) {

                Mockito.when(mock.eq(ArgumentMatchers.eq("z")).leq(ArgumentMatchers.eq("a")).in(ArgumentMatchers.eq("a"))).thenReturn("a");

                Mockito.when(mock.eq(ArgumentMatchers.eq("z")).leq(ArgumentMatchers.eq("b")).in(ArgumentMatchers.eq("b"))).thenReturn("b");

                Mockito.when(mock.eq(ArgumentMatchers.eq("z")).leq(ArgumentMatchers.eq("c")).in(ArgumentMatchers.eq("c"))).thenReturn("c");

                Mockito.when(mock.eq(ArgumentMatchers.eq("z")).leq(ArgumentMatchers.eq("d")).in(ArgumentMatchers.eq("d"))).thenReturn("d");

                Mockito.when(mock.eq(ArgumentMatchers.eq("z")).leq(ArgumentMatchers.eq("e")).in(ArgumentMatchers.eq("d"))).thenReturn("e");

            } else {
                Mockito.when(mock.eq("z").in("a")).thenReturn("gg");
            }
        });
        // return null ,  i hope mock return "a"
        assertEquals("a", new Link("z").eq("z").leq("a").in("a"));

        assertEquals("b", new Link("z").eq("z").leq("b").in("b"));

        assertEquals("c", new Link("z").eq("z").leq("c").in("c"));

        assertEquals("d", new Link("z").eq("z").leq("d").in("d"));

        assertEquals("e", new Link("z").eq("z").leq("e").in("d"));

    }


    class Link {

        private String name;
        private String age;

        public Link(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public Link eq(String a) {
            return this;
        }

        public Link leq(String a) {
            return this;
        }

        public String in(String a) {
            return a;
        }

    }
}



